# Haproxy(Openshift) fails to check Rails 4 root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, haproxy

I'm using Openshift, Haproxy, Ruby on Rails with Postgresql as backend. I have deployed everything successfully but Haproxy fails to send a HTTP request to the root path of my rails app.

app-root/logs/haproxy.log

```
[ALERT] 114/053517 (469622) : proxy 'express' has no server available!    
[WARNING] server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404
```

app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log

```
ERROR -- : Could not connect to the application.  Check if the application is stopped.
```

app-root/logs/ruby.log

```
"OPTIONS /products HTTP/1.0" 404 1351 "-" "-"
```

routes.rb

```
  root :to => 'products#index'
```

haproxy.cfg

```
global  
   maxconn 4096  
   stats socket /var/lib/{ID}/haproxy//run/stats level admin

defaults  
   log   global  
   mode   http  
   option   httplog  
   option   dontlognull
   option http-server-close  
   retries   3  
   option redispatch  
   maxconn   128
   timeout http-request   10s
   timeout queue 1m
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout client 1m
   timeout server 1m
   timeout http-keep-alive 10s
   timeout check 10s

listen stats xxx.xxx.xxx.131:8080
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /

listen express xxx.xxx.xxx.130:8080
  cookie GEAR insert indirect nocache
  option httpchk /

  balance leastconn
  server local-gear xxx.xxx.xxx.129:8080 check fall 2 rise 3 inter 200 cookie local-{APP_ID}
```

I have deleted the index.html in my public folder (Rails). But, when I add the index.html file to the public folder again everything works and I can access my app under: app_name-appdomain.rhcloud.com/products
Which is not perfect, because I want access it without adding /products to the URL.

Thank you for any help!
Please let me know if you need any further details on the setup

Cheers!

Comment: I also tried: option httpchk /products

Comment: I am facing the same problem with nodejs app.

Comment: Are you still having the same problem? Did you fix it yet?

Comment: sorry for the very late answer, but I couldn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SO there are few things you can try to get around this, one of them should solve your problem.

1. OPTION A: try changing the line `option httpchk /` to `option httpchk GET /`
   If this does not work, make sure you have index.html in your webroot. If you do not prefer this approach or want to point to some other html file (which exists in web root), you can modify it to `option httpchk some-other-file.html`
2. OPTION B: simply comment this line, but it would affect haproxy health check.
3. OPTION C: modify the line to

> option httpchk OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www

where www is your app link, like, XXX-yyy.rhcloud.com

4.An additional observation, haproxy might fail to check Rails path, as the time-out in the last line of haproxy.cfg seems pretty less. Try changing "200" (2ms) to "20000" (20s).